# Does gvimfullscreen.dll working with gVim 9.0 on Windows?

Tags: gvim, vim-windows, microsoft-windows

I used to use `gvimfullscreen.dll` to toggle a full screen window state on gvim for Windows. It made gvim full screen, not maximised, with no titlebar.

I have not used gvim on Windows for some time until recently and it's no longer working for me. The many mentions of this file I have found on the internet are old and there are no discussions about it no longer working. I am using gvim for Windows 9.0 and I probably last used it successfully with v8.0.

I get this error:

> Error detected while processing function ToggleFullScreen:
>
> line 4:
>
> E364: Library call failed for "ToggleFullScreen()"

https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2596

```
" Fullscreen with Alt-Enter
function! ToggleFullScreen()
  if has('gui_gtk2')
    :call system("wmctrl -ir " . v:windowid . " -b toggle,fullscreen")
  elseif has('gui_win32')
    :call libcallnr(expand("$VIM") . "/win/gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)
  endif
endfunction
set <M-CR>=\<ESC>\<CR>
map <silent> <M-CR> :call ToggleFullScreen()<CR>
```

Comment: Are you using a Win32 or an amd64 version of gVim? I suspect that the binary distribution is  compiled for Win32. You can figure out using the `:version` command

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I am using the 64-bit version of gvim and I actually was using the 64-bit dll as well, but I renamed as I thought it would be less hassle than editing my config.

Comment: Good :-) Maybe the problem is that the `$VIM` variable is not pointing to the correct folder or that the DLL is not placed correctly. Did my answer solved your problem?

Comment: There is also a similar plugin: https://github.com/imranZERO/wintweak.gvim

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks. I'll check that out if I can't get this working. I have already tried another one that works, but it's a bit too aggressive as you cannot alt-tab any other windows over it when it full screen. https://github.com/xolox/vim-shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a 64-bit version of Vim you have to adapt the call to use the 64 bit version of the dll:

```
" Fullscreen with Alt-Enter
function! ToggleFullScreen()
  if has('gui_gtk2')
    :call system("wmctrl -ir " . v:windowid . " -b toggle,fullscreen")
  elseif has('gui_win32')
    :call libcallnr(expand("$VIM") . "/win/gvimfullscreen_64.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)
  endif
endfunction
set <M-CR>=\<ESC>\<CR>
map <silent> <M-CR> :call ToggleFullScreen()<CR>
```

The `gvimfullscreen_64.dll` is available at: [gvimfullscreen_64.dll](https://github.com/derekmcloughlin/gvimfullscreen_win32/blob/master/gvimfullscreen_64.dll)

The code suppose the dll is placed in a `win` folder next to the `vim90` folder.

```
" Fullscreen with Alt-Enter
function! ToggleFullScreen()
  if has('gui_gtk2')
    :call system("wmctrl -ir " . v:windowid . " -b toggle,fullscreen")
  elseif has('gui_win32')
    :call libcallnr(expand("$VIM") . "/vim90/win/gvimfullscreen_64.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)
  endif
endfunction
set <M-CR>=\<ESC>\<CR>
map <silent> <M-CR> :call ToggleFullScreen()<CR>
```

If the `win` folder is a subfolder of the `vim90` folder the code must be adapted as follow:

You can determine if you are using a 32 bit or a 64 bit version of Vim by looking at the second line of the result of the `:version` Vim command

```
VIM - vi Improved 9.0 ...
MS-Windows 64-bit GUI/Console version ...
...
```

vs.

```
VIM - vi Improved 9.0 ...
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI/Console version ...
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I edited the config twice, using both versions of your changes and I used the .dll file from your link and I still get the same error. I used the line `:call libcallnr("gvimfullscreen.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)` as my `$VIM` is set to `$HOME\vimfiles` on Windows. The file in the same directory as `gvim.exe`.

Comment: Have you tested it yourself? Does it work with gvim 9.0?

Comment: It works for me, I have tested it. If your `$VIM` points to  `$HOME\vimfiles` the `gvimfullscreen.dll` should be in `$HOME\vimfiles\win` (if you are using the first version of the code).

Comment: This is confusing. Are you using Windows 11? I am.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. But I'm very doubtful that it is the origin of the difference. Maybe could you the call to the DLL(`:call libcallnr(expand("$VIM") . "/vim90/win/gvimfullscreen_64.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)`) by : `:echo expand("$VIM") . "/win/gvimfullscreen.dll"` and report the message you get when you hit `<M-CR>`.

Comment: `:call libcallnr(expand("$VIM") . "/vim90/gvimfullscreen_64.dll", "ToggleFullScreen", 0)` (path corrected) gives the same `E364` error and `:echo expand("$VIM") . "/win/gvimfullscreen_64.dll"`returns `$HOME\vimfiles/win/gvimfullscreen_64.dll`. The file is there and in the program directory. Could it be due to slashes and backslashes?

Comment: In a Window console what is the output of the following command: `echo %home%\vimfiles\win`

Comment: I included the file. `>echo %home%\vimfiles\win\gvimfullscreen_64.dll
%home%\vimfiles\win\gvimfullscreen_64.dll`

Comment: `>echo %userprofile%\vimfiles\win\gvimfullscreen_64.dll
C:\Users\jason\vimfiles\win\gvimfullscreen_64.dll`

Comment: `$HOME` expands successfully in the gvim command mode.

Comment: Do you have the Dll in: `C:\Users\jason\vimfiles\win`?

Comment: Yes, and the program directory.

Comment: If you have the right DLL (e.g.: matching the architecture of VIM) in the folder indicated by `%home%\vimfiles\win` then it should work. I have no other idea :-/ sorry.

Comment: It seems that there are a lot of people who have experienced this problem if you search for the error number. That error number seems to come up just for this .dll and it's often unexplained why this is happening on some machines and not on others. I will write a answer later explaining what I am using instead. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, but only by using another plugin. I'll write an answer in a little while.

Comment: Thanks I'm impatient to know how its ends ;-)

Comment: I added my solution. Cheers.

Comment: @paradroid Not sure if I'm reading the above right, but in [this message](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38676/does-gvimfullscreen-dll-working-with-gvim-9-0-on-windows#comment70758_38679) you said that you used the command `libcallnr(expand("$VIM") . "/vim90/gvimfullscreen_64.dll"` (without `/win/`) but as far as I can tell from your other comments the file is actually in the `win` subfolder. Could you confirm if you've tried the command *without* editing the paths?

Comment: @Rich Yes, I think you have found the problem. I forgot that I had since defined `$VIM`. I completely overlooked that line as I thought there couldn't be anything wrong with it since it worked previously.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get `gvimfullscreen.dll` working and searching the web showed that quite a few people have had this problem but there was no solution.

EDIT: [This comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38676/does-gvimfullscreen-dll-working-with-gvim-9-0-on-windows/38679?noredirect=1#comment70945_38679) solves the problem, as I had forgotten that I had defined `$VIM` to another location.

I ended up using this plugin: https://github.com/kkoenig/wimproved.vim, but I found it had the same problem as `gvimfullscreen.dll` in that it did not return to the previous screen size when the window is restored. I then found this vimscript which saves and restores the screen size:

https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Restore_screen_size_and_position

So in my `gvimrc` I source that script and use some logic to use the plugin and restore the screen size using the functions from the script.

```
" Restore window positions
source $VIM/vimrc.d/restore_position.vim

" Fullscreen toggle with F11
function! ToggleFullScreen()
  if has('gui_gtk2')
    call system("wmctrl -ir " . v:windowid . " -b toggle,fullscreen")
  elseif has('gui_win32')
    if !exists("s:fullscr")
      let s:fullscr = 0
    endif
    if (s:fullscr == 0)
      call ScreenSave()
      WToggleFullscreen
      let s:fullscr = 1
    elseif (s:fullscr == 1)
      WToggleFullscreen
      call ScreenRestore()
      let s:fullscr = 0
    endif
  endif
endfunction
map <silent> <F11> :call ToggleFullScreen()<CR>
```

Everything works great now.