# Checkhealth - ERROR: $VIM is invalid: $HOME/.config/vim

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I share most of the configuration for vim and neovim between them and I set `$VIM` like this…

```
if has('unix')
  let $VIM = "$HOME/.config/vim"
elseif has('win32')
  let $VIM = "$HOME/vimfiles"
endif
```

…which makes it possible to set file paths elsewhere throughout the configuration for both Linux and Windows without using conditional statements (in most cases, but not all).

According to `:h $VIM` this is fine and pretty much the intended purpose of the variable. So why does `:checkhealth` give this error message in the new version of nvim (0.8.0)?

```
## Configuration                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  - ERROR: $VIM is invalid: $HOME/.config/vim
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking that the only reason you need $VIM set that way is because [you reference it](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/38676/343) in your personal config files? Would just using a different variable work for you? `:let NOTVIM = "$HOME/vimfiles"`

Comment: @Rich That's what I have done in the end. I defined `$VIMFILES`. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The health of `$VIM` variable is checked with the following logic<sup>[1](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/cfdb4cbada8c65aa57e69776bcc0f7b8b298317a/runtime/autoload/health/nvim.vim#L15-L19)</sup>:

```
" If $VIM is empty we don't care. Else make sure it is valid.
if !empty($VIM) && !filereadable($VIM.'/runtime/doc/nvim.txt')
  let ok = v:false
  call health#report_error('$VIM is invalid: '.$VIM)
endif
```

You must not have `$HOME/.config/vim/runtime/doc/nvim.txt`, or if you have it, you must not have read-permission for that file (the latter case is highly unlikely). That's the reason for the error you're facing.

```
## Configuration
  - ERROR: $VIM is invalid: $HOME/.config/vim
```

---

The logic above tells us that `$VIM` is expected to point to the directory where vim's system files reside. As for the reason behind, a look at the nvim source code reveals that the environment variable `$VIM` is accessed only twice in the who codebase.

- To set system vimrc file<sup>[2](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/cfdb4cbada8c/src/nvim/globals.h#L58-L60)</sup>
- When checking for `$VIMRUNTIME` and finding it nil<sup>[3](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/cfdb4cbada8c/src/nvim/os/env.c#L919-L934)</sup>.

(`$VIM` is also handled when you do `:echo $VIM`, but that comes later in the execution time, and by then both `$VIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME` and most if not all variables have been set already.)

So, if we've got our own vimrc file (which means vim won't need the system vimrc) and we've set `$VIMRUNTIME` properly (pointing to where vim's system runtime files exist), then the value of `$VIM` should invite no complication. We can simply ignore the error put out by `:checkhealth`.

BUT if we've not set `$VIMRUNTIME` and have set `$VIM` to an arbitrary location, then the value of `$VIMRUNTIME` will be set wrongly at startup. See the stacktrace at the startup on a breakpoint at `vim_getenv`<sup>[3](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/cfdb4cbada8c/src/nvim/os/env.c#L919-L934)</sup>.

```
gdb> where
#0  vim_getenv (name=0x7ff6f47638b9 <__func__.2+969> "VIMRUNTIME") at E:/projects/neovim/master/src/nvim/os/env.c:901
#1  0x00007ff6f44d62da in runtimepath_default (clean_arg=false) at E:/projects/neovim/master/src/nvim/runtime.c:1511
#2  0x00007ff6f446720f in set_init_1 (clean_arg=false) at E:/projects/neovim/master/src/nvim/option.c:316
#3  0x00007ff6f43ea95e in early_init (paramp=0x850f1ff530) at E:/projects/neovim/master/src/nvim/main.c:201
#4  0x00007ff6f43eab4d in wmain (argc=1, argv_w=0x22b48aa44b0) at E:/projects/neovim/master/src/nvim/main.c:257
#5  0x00007ff6f42513da in __tmainCRTStartup () at C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:326
#6  0x00007ff6f4251506 in mainCRTStartup () at C:/M/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c:206
```

It's this case that will cause problems such as vim not finding syntax file ($VIMRUNTIME/syntax/syntax.vim), etc. Otherwise, we can use `$VIM` as our own personal environment variable.

---

Comment: @Rich  I still don't understand. Could you explain what you misread? Or maybe write an answer explaining it.

Comment: I read this: "The environment variable "$VIM" is used to locate various user files for Vim,
**such as the user startup script ".vimrc"**. [...] 1. The value defined by the $VIM environment variable.  You can use this to make Vim look in a specific directory for its support files. setenv VIM **/home/paul/vim**" (emphasis mine) ...and inferred that you were supposed to be able to use `$VIM` like how the OP wants to. Having re-read it, I think it's intended use is a bit more subtle and specialised than that, although I'm still figuring out *precisely* what that intended use is.

Comment: If I ever figure out what that is I'll write a frame challenge answer to this question explaining some other ways of achieving the goal (or you can, if the vim_use peeps clarify!)

Comment: @Rich I have a feeling, that instead of a **user startup script** it should mean the **system startup script**

Comment: @Rich and ChristianBrabandt, I added the explanation for $VIM. Please see if makes sense.